# Best way to send data to a non-browser client behind NAT and firewalls?

Tags: http, tcp, stream, push, nat

Here is the scenario:

1. Client #1 put some info to the server (using an HTTP request)
2. Server keeps that info and wait for client #2 to put his info too. Time between client #1 and client #2 calls can be from a couple of seconds to several hours.
3. When client #2 put his info to server, server return client #1 infos to client #2 through the HTTP request.
4. Server then need to return the client #2 infos to client #1.

How can I return client #2 infos to client #1, assuming that client #1 cannot be directly reached (NAT, firewall) and that the time between the two calls can be very long?

I would like to avoid client #1 to regularly poke the server... Clients are not using a web browser to connect to the server but a custom application where we have total control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client will have to poke the server periodically, if the client closes its connection anytime between steps 1 and 4.  Otherwise, let the client keep its initial connection open waiting for a [server-side push](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology) of the data, even if it takes hours, then close the connection once the data arrives.

Comment: thanks for the answer, so if I have a web server with using python/django,php or other language, I just have to wait before sending the response until I have the infos. If the connection drops, the clients just have to request again. Considering that the client is a custom software (not a browser), is there a more efficient way to achieve it?

Comment: Not with TCP, no.  Either the client stays connected the whole time until the data finally arrives, or it drops out and reconnects periodically to poll for the data.